# Как получить значения атрибутов класса из списка в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть какой-то класс:

```py
class MyClass:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
```

Я хочу получить значения атрибутов экземпляра этого класса, которые входят в список attrs.

```py
attrs = ['a', 'd']
```

Как я могу получить на выходе словарь result, содержащий только нужные мне атрибуты со значениями?

```py
{'a': 1, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До этого я не знал, но оказывается специально для этого есть такой простой метод getattr:

```py
my_class = MyClass()
result = {}
[result.update({attr: getattr(my_class, attr)}) for attr in attrs]
```

Comment: `result = {a:getattr(my_class, a) for a in attrs}`

Comment: Да, так лучше, спасибо)